# Classification of representation-finite 1-Gorenstein algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory

All involved algebras are assumed to finite dimensional quiver algebras over an algebraically closed field.
Is the classification of representation-finite 1-Gorenstein algebras known, generalising the famous classification of representation-finite hereditary algebras?

Comment: Dear @Henry.L, I have rolled back your edit. The changes to grammar were unnecessary and the two tags you added did not seem relevant (the algebras in this question are neither commutative nor Lie)

Comment: @YemonChoi will change the habit of editing in a bulk. Thanks for the advice!